# autohotkey scancode in combination

Tags: autohotkey, scancodes

I am having trouble getting either of the following to work:

```
VKFF & a::^a
SC163 & a::^a
```

This fails with "invalid hotkey" if I try to run the script.
The scan code alone works just fine

```
SC163::^a
```

I am guessing there is a syntax issue... Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

```
#InstallKeybdHook
SC163 & a::
    Send, ^a
    KeyHistory
return
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to use VK and SC together.

Add it to a directive to check if it's pushed or not, then add your `a::` hotkey to that directive.

It should look something like this:

```
#If GetKeyState("VKFFSC163", "P")
a::^a
#If
```